# Wordpress Post not retunring success

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a wordpress post return success I have tried various techniques and I feel this is close but still not getting a success message

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#send_btn").click(function(){

 var points = jQuery('#points').val();
var comments = jQuery('#comments').val();

     var allData = {
action: 'functionRedeempoints',
points: points,
comments:comments
}
   var data = JSON.stringify(allData);   

       alert( data);

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : 'json',
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : data,
         success: function(response) {
        if(response.success) {
         alert('do i get here');// i never get to here no idea why
        }
        else {
           // Do something else
        }
     }
  });
});
}); //Modal event Ends
```

In My functions php I have foloiwng

```
wp_localize_script( 'inkthemes', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));

function functionRedeempoints() {
 wp_send_json_success(true);
}

add_action("wp_ajax_redeempoints", "functionRedeempoints");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_redeempoints", "functionRedeempoints");
```

Comment: It almost like its not finding the function even though I have it functions.php

Comment: try not stringifying the data passing it to the JQuery.ajax request. Change add_action to -> add_action(wp_ajax_funcitonReddempoints.....(You have no such function as redeempoints.. ?!?)

Comment: can see ur full answer and its not an answer

Comment: One of the things i suppose for a problem is the JSON stringifying of allData- no need. Rename add_action wp_ajax_redeempoints to wp_ajax_funcitonRedeempoints. And if you are using this ajax functionality ad the admin part of Wordpress you do not need to declare MyAjax.

Comment: actually yes u do cause the data type is json !